# Limit number of rows and columns in OpenOffice Calc

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-calc

Is there a way to limit the number of rows and columns shown in a sheet in OpenOffice Calc?

I have resorted to manually hiding rows and columns outside the area that I want, but this is tedious, and is reset when using AutoFilter.

Note that I'm looking for a per-sheet setting, not a per-user or per-installation setting.

In Excel, there seems to be a very roundabout way to do this, but I haven't been able to find an OpenOffice equivalent: http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excelformulas/ss/2011-05-14-excel-2010-limit-rows-tutorial.htm

Answer (score 1):

Of the various workarounds available, to me it seems like hiding the rows and columns is best.  Here is a subroutine that will do it automatically:

```vb
Sub HideRowsAndColumns(iLastVisibleRow As Integer, iLastVisibleCol As Integer)
    oController = ThisComponent.CurrentController
    oSheet = oController.ActiveSheet
    document   = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Frame
    dispatcher = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")
    oCellRange = oSheet.getCellRangeByPosition(_
        0, iLastVisibleRow, 0, oSheet.Rows.Count - 1)
    oController.select(oCellRange)
    dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:HideRow", "", 0, Array())
    oCellRange = oSheet.getCellRangeByPosition(_
        iLastVisibleCol, 0, oSheet.Columns.Count - 1, 0)
    oController.select(oCellRange)
    dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:HideColumn", "", 0, Array())
    oCellRange = oSheet.getCellRangeByPosition(0, 0, 0, 0)
    oController.select(oCellrange)
End Sub
```

For example, the following routine could be called when the document is opened (`Tools -> Customize -> Events`):

```vb
Sub DoHideRowsAndCols
    HideRowsAndColumns(20,10)
End Sub
```

In LibreOffice, `AutoFilter` did not unhide the rows.  However it did in Apache OpenOffice.  So for AOO, the routine would need to be called again after doing an `AutoFilter`.

Another alternative is that instead of hiding the cells, protect them to prevent editing.  See https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/17106/is-it-possible-to-impose-a-limit-columns-and-rows-on-spreadsheet-size/.

It may be possible to add an event handler to prevent scrolling beyond certain rows.  For an example of a spreadsheet event handler, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35240690/how-to-scroll-all-libreoffice-calc-spreadsheet-sheets-together-or-other-3d-li/35244220#35244220.

However I think that adding such a handler would be very irritating for the user.  They would try to click on a cell only to have nothing happen, or perhaps the view would suddenly scroll back to the original view.

Comment: How do you run this script manually?

Comment: Add the code using *Tools -> Macros -> Organize Macros -> LibreOffice Basic*.  Then go to *Tools -> Macros -> Run Macro* and find `DoHideRowsAndCols` .